# Empty lines between results in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping this site:

https://doctor.webmd.com/find-a-doctor/specialty/psychiatry/arizona/phoenix

From that list I'm loading and scraping the data for each doctor. 
The values in the results look fine, but the format is not, since it has an empty row for each record. This is the code I'm using:

```
import scrapy


class MainSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'main_spider'
    #allowed_domains = [''link'']
    start_urls = ['https://doctor.webmd.com/find-a-doctor/specialty/psychiatry/arizona/phoenix?pagenumber=1']

    def parse(self, response):



        doctors_urls =  (response.xpath('//*[@class="doctorName"]//@href').extract())
        for doctor in doctors_urls:
            doctor = response.urljoin(doctor)
            print (doctor) 
            yield scrapy.Request(url=doctor,callback=self.parse_doctor)
        next_page  = response.xpath('//*[@id="next-onRight"]//@href').extract_first() 
        if next_page:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page,callback=self.parse)

    def parse_doctor(self,response):

        yield {"Name": response.xpath('//*[@class="header"]//*[@itemprop="name"]//text()').extract_first(),
         "Speciality":response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="medicalSpecialty"]//*[@itemprop="name"]//text()').extract_first(),
         "Years of experience":response.xpath('//*[@class="profile-content"]//*[@class="subheader content-body years"]//text()').extract_first(),
         "Employer": response.xpath('//*[@class="address"]//*[@class="practice"]//text()').extract_first(),
         "Address": response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="address"]//*[@itemprop="streetaddress"]//text()').extract(),
         "City": response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="address"]//*[@itemprop="addressLocality"]//text()').extract(),
         "Url": response.url}
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

[image]

And this the options of the text editor:

[image]

Besides this, the header appears twice in the first rows:

[image]

Comment: you have wrong indentions. And you didn't show output.

Comment: I don't know what you have in output but maybe you should use `strip()` to remove spaces, tabs and new line `"\n"`

Comment: I run code and save to csv using `-o output.csv` and I get file without empty lines. Maybe you use wrong options when you open it. You could open it in normal text editor

Comment: @furas Wich text editor are you using? I tried with libre office and gdocs and the result is the same for both. I updated the options I'm using in the question.

Comment: normal text editor - Notepad, Notepad++, Geany. How do you create csv file ? Do you use built-in option `-o` to write it or you use own function to write it ?

Comment: @furas yes the biult-in function -o -output.csv

Comment: as I know Windows use "\r\n" as end of line - it is two chars. Maybe Libre Office treats it as end of two lines.  `scrapy` should save data in `UTF-8` so you could check character set `UTF-8` . I uses Linux which uses single char "\n" as end of line and can't check it.